# Invoke ObjectARX acedDisableDefaultARXExceptionHandler from c#

Tags: c#, autocad, autocad-plugin, objectarx

I'm developing an AutoCAD Plugin, and I can't capture unhandled exceptions.

Tried to use CurrentDomain.UnhandledException and Application.ThreadException, but none of this work.

I would like try the solution suggested in this post:

[How to catch unhandled exceptions thrown in AutoCAD.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384442/how-to-catch-unhandled-exceptions-thrown-in-autocad-net)

But don't know how to do it. Probably this could be the best solution, so I can show my own Error Dialog (and send report functionality) avoiding AutoCAD's Error Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to catch all (or even any) native exceptions in your managed code. At the very least you would need AutoCAD 2013+ with fibers disabled (FIBERWORLD = 0), and even then it's a stretch.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. I'll try to catch all errors in this project. Hope inherited controls don't throw any error.

Answer (score 0):

calling acedDisableDefaultARXExceptionHandler to disable not change anything for me

```
    // EntryPoint may vary across autocad versions
    [DllImport("acad.exe", EntryPoint = "?acedDisableDefaultARXExceptionHandler@@YAXH@Z")]
    public static extern void acedDisableDefaultARXExceptionHandler(int value);
```